# Multiple commands produce frameworks issue (related to usage of cocoapod)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, podspec, podfile

I have two frameworks 'GeneralABC' and 'GeneralXYZ'. Both of them have the same interface but different business logic. I define their module_name in podspec as General, so that other projects using my framework only need to define which General framework(GeneralABC or GeneralXYZ) they want to use in their Podfile, without changing their codes. (i.e. in their code file, they can always say import General)

In my example project, i have two targets, each target using different General framework. My Podfile is as follows:

```
target 'Example_ABC' do
    pod 'GeneralABC'
end

target 'Example_XYZ' do
     pod 'GeneralXYZ'
end
```

however when i try to build one of my target in xcode, I have got the following error
message

```
Multiple commands produce '/MYPATH/General.framework':
1) Target 'GeneralABC' has create directory command with output 'MYPATH/General.framework'
2) Target 'GeneralXYZ' has create directory command with output 'MYPATH/General.framework'

Multiple commands produce '/MYPATH/General.framework':
1)Target 'GeneralABC' has link command with output 'MYPATH/General.framework'
2)Target 'GeneralXYZ' has link command with output 'MYPATH/General.framework'
```

It can be solved by two approaches:

1. changing the workspace settings to legacy build system. however I don't think it is a solution in the future.
2. remove one of the target in the Podfile, and `pod update` every time we build the target. however, it is not so nice for maintenance and our build process.

is there any solution that i can manipulate my Podfile, so that i can fix the issue?

I appreciate very much of any suggestions.
Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find the exact solution that I want (1 pod file maintain all the targets). However, after some discussions with our teammates. we come up another kind of solution, so that we don't have to worry about the deprecated legacy build system.

solution are as follows:

create 2 podfile (i.e. 1 for target 'Example_ABC' the other for 'Example_XYZ')

create 2 workspace file (i.e. 1 for target 'Example_ABC' the other for 'Example_XYZ')

a mini shell script, that link the Podfile_ABC or Podfile_XYZ, when do the pod install/update/deintegrate

Comment: can you maybe share the Podfiles?